# Getting Value from a Child Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to get the value using the function getValues from react-hook-form from a child component that I have created (bear in mind this is an example and there is some logic of having created the component in this fashion). When I click on "Print Values" it doesn't get the value of authorId. Any ideas?

These are the two components:

```js
const { register, control, getValues } = useForm();

<Button
  onClick={() => {
    console.log(getValues());
  }}
>
  Print Values
</Button>

<FormControl variant="outlined">
  <InputLabel>Author</InputLabel>
  <Controller
    {...register}
    control={control}
    name="authorId"
    render={({ field }) => (
      <CustomDropdown control={control} category="Author" field={field} />
    )}
  />
</FormControl>
```

CustomDropdown.js

```js
const CustomDropdown = ({ field }) => {
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = React.useState("");

  <Select
    {...field}
    value={selectedValues || ""}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setSelectedValues(e.target.value);
    }}
  >
    return <MenuItem key="1" value="1">
      Option 1
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem key="2" value="2">
      Option 2
    </MenuItem>
  </Select>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things. First, the `register` method needs to be called with the name of the input.
In the controller component you're not calling `register`

```js
<Controller
  {...register}
```

Instead change it to:

```
<Controller
  {...register("authorId")}
```

Also you're not using the `useForm` hook to control the value of the `CustomDropdown` component.

Rather you're controlling the value using its own react state that the `useForm` hook is unaware of

```js
const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = React.useState("");
// ...
onChange={(e) => { setSelectedValues(e.target.value) }}
```

One solution is to pass the `setValue` method and `value` to the `CustomDropdown` component as properties.

First file

```js
const { register, control, getValues, setValue } = useForm();

const setAuthorIdValue = (value) => setValue("authorId", value);

<Button
  onClick={() => {
    console.log(getValues());
  }}
>
  Print Values
</Button>

<FormControl variant="outlined">
  <InputLabel>Author</InputLabel>
  <Controller
    {...register("authorId")}
    control={control}
    name="authorId"
    render={({ field }) => (
      <CustomDropdown
        control={control}
        category="Author"
        field={field}
        value={getValues("authorId")}
        setValue={setAuthorIdValue}
      />
    )}
  />
</FormControl>
```

CustomDropdown.js

```js
const CustomDropdown = ({ field, value, setValue }) => {
  return <Select
    {...field}
    value={value || ""}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setValue(e.target.value);
    }}
  >
    return <MenuItem key="1" value="1">
      Option 1
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem key="2" value="2">
      Option 2
    </MenuItem>
  </Select>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you just need to output the value you should use the current scope**

```
const CustomDropdown = () => {
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState("value 1");
  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={()=>console.log(selectedValues)}> Get value </button>
    <select 
      value={selectedValues}
      onChange={e => setSelectedValues(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="value 1"> Value 1</option>
        <option value="value 2"> Value 2</option>
        <option value="value 3"> Value 3</option>
      </select>
    </>
  )
}
```

**If you need the value for other purposes use [the Context Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)**

**Edit:** Example of passing values from child to parent with the Context Hook. In your case you will need to define the `useState` in App.js like this:

App.js

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Child from './Child.js'

export const MyContext = createContext("N0thing")

function App() {
  const [getValue, changeValue] = useState(0)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      <MyContext.Provider value={{getValue, changeValue}}>
          <Child/>
      </MyContext.Provider>
          Renderd by Parent {getValue}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child.js

```
import {useContext} from 'react'
import {MyContext} from './App.js'

const Child = () => {
    const myContext = useContext(MyContext)
    return (
        <>
        Renderd by Child {myContext.getValue}
        <button onClick={()=>myContext.changeValue(myContext.getValue + 1)}> Change value from Child Componet </button>    
        </>
    )
}
 export default Child;
```

I hope I understand you correctly and that this can help.

Comment: Hi @RustyJames, would it be possible for you to show an example of how to obtain the child's value using context hook?

Comment: Se my updated answer.